# Could it be possible that 2 different accounts could see different metadata on the same sandbox?

Tags: salesforce

I have a Salesforce sandbox and 2 accounts to access this sandbox.
Could it be possible that 2 different accounts could see different metadata on the same sandbox?

For example

With account 1 logined, the Account object has been customized by adding field A to its definition

With account 2 logined, the Account object has been customized by adding field B (and dont have field A above) to its definition

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if the Users are in different Roles which define different [Field-Level Security](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutoverview.htm&language=en_US). Refer to the following from the Salesforce documentation.

> Restrict users’ access to view and edit fields by any means, including reports, search results, list views, related lists, email and mail merge templates, custom links, Connect Offline, the API, and when synchronizing data or importing personal data.

Comment: Thank you, what i am looking for is different object metadata for different users. The above field-level security, as far as i know, still retains the same object definition, just support to hide or show particular field based on user role, but the field still exists

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying. The metadata XML is generated via the API, which is filtered by field level security. If "account 2" doesn't have view permission on "field A" it will not appear in the metadata for that user.

Comment: Thank, it's really cool! In fact, i am using a salesforce sandbox for 2 different development branches. Now, one branch is finished and i want create change set for prod deployment. But i really dont want to deploy changes of the other unfinished branch. So, i wonder the field level security could be applied within creating change set so that i only deploy a certain object with its new fields yielded from finished development branch only?

Comment: That might work but could get difficult to manage. Probably beyond the scope of StackOverflow as release management is pretty tricky.